# How to measure consumed memory of a function (or a loop) in c++

Tags: c++, performance, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been working on an optimization program and need to know the exact memory size consumed by a certain loop (or function).

I need to get the exact quantity of memory consumed and keep track of it in an array inside the program for later use.

I'm using GCC on Linux.

Comment: It depends. Which OS? Which compiler?

Comment: There are several solutions there, and the question is way too broad in it's current form.

Comment: Do you want to measure the data used by a function, or the code size?

Comment: Nope mainly the data.

Comment: Add hooks to the allocator. Don't know why this question is downvoted; it seems perfectly sensible.